# Domain Events v Event Aggregator v... other

Tags: event-handling, domain-driven-design, eventaggregator, domain-events

I have a composite structure in my domain where the leaf node (Allocation) has a DurationChanged event that I would like to use at the top of my presentation layer view model structure (in the TimeSheetViewModel), and I am wondering what the best way is to get to it.

Options that come to mind include:

1. Subscribe to it in the TimeSheetComposite. Each composite is ultimately composed of Allocations, and the TimeSheetComposite is the Model to the TimeSheetViewModel. It seems I would also need an event in the TimeSheetComposite that gets fired when a child DurationChanged event is fired; the TimeSheetViewModel would subscribe to the latter event.
2. Ignore the DurationChanged event and just follow the INPC chain that bubbles up to the TimeSheetViewModel when AllocationViewModel.Amount is changed. I wouldn't have a useful piece of information, specifically the old Amount prior to the edit, but I can calculate the needed end results cheaply enough if necessary.
3. Make the DurationChanged event a [Domain Event](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/); I do not currently use domain events, but I sure like the concept and it looks like there is enough code in Udi's article to get started with it.
4. Set up some sort of Event Aggregator to publish & subscribe to DurationChanged. I am not very sure yet what the difference is yet between Domain Events and Event Aggregators are, and whether they are complimentary or alternative approaches to solving the same thing. The [implementation here using Rx looks promising](http://jfromaniello.blogspot.com/2010/04/event-aggregator-with-reactive.html).

In this design, the TimeSheetViewModel needs to know when an Allocation.Duration has changed so it can get a new total of all allocation durations by date.

How would you provide the DurationChanged notice?

Cheers,
Berryl

## Domain Composite structure & event

[image]

## Presentation layer structure

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up listening for the leaf event in the (TimeSheet)Composite, and then essentially re-throwing a similar event there to make it easy for the (TimeSheet)ViewModel to listen to it.

When I understand DomainEvents / EventAggregators better I will revisit this one.

Cheers,
Berryl